# FDF, MS CRM and iframe

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4, fdf

I'm looking for help with using iframe with a FDF. It also has to display in IE because we use MS CRM. The PDF that the FDF is referencing is encrypted so I can't do any server side merging (I don't think). I've looked at the FDF-Toolkit but it's little over kill for just displaying, also I have heard that it doesn't always work.

Thank you for any help that you can offer

Answer (score 0):

Use the XFDF format. It is basicly a simple XML format ( here is  the Spec: http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/xml/xfdf_2.0_draft.pdf ). Make sure the PDF you refer to is served from the same server and that the MIME type is correct (application/vnd.adobe.xfdf).